# Check if user exists in a database(PostgreSQL) with NestJS

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs, backend

I'm building a game at the moment with a frontend(Vue.js) and a backend in(NestJS). For the data in the backend, I implemented a PostgreSQL database. I followed some guides on how to implement the endpoint for http-requests, and they are working fine for now.

Now, I want to implement some logical checks before creating a user:
If the username already exists in the database, I don't want to recreate the user.

Some ideas on how I can implement this?
I thought about the class-transformer in NestJS but, I didn't find any command which could help me with it.

Here is what my code is looking like atm:

user.entitiy.ts:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class users_trans {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { users_trans } from './users.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(users_trans) private usersRepo: Repository<users_trans>) {}

    findAll(): Promise<users_trans[]> {
        return this.usersRepo.find();
    }

    create(newUser){
    this.usersRepo.insert(newUser)
    }

    update(usertoUpdate){
        this.usersRepo.update(usertoUpdate.id,usertoUpdate);
    }

    delete(id){
        this.usersRepo.delete(id);
    }
}
```

user.controller.ts:

```
import {UsersService} from './users.service';
import {users_trans} from './users.entity';
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Delete, Param, HttpCode } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService){}

    @Get('all')
    async getAll():Promise<users_trans[]>{
        return await this.usersService.findAll();
    }

    @Post('add')
    @HttpCode(201)
    createUser(@Body() newUser:any){
        this.usersService.create(newUser);
    }

    @Post('update')
    @HttpCode(201)
    updateUser(@Body() usertoUpdate:any){
        this.usersService.update(usertoUpdate);
    }

    @Delete('delete/:id')
    @HttpCode(200)
    deleteEmployee(@Param('id') id){
        this.usersService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

user.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { UserController } from './users.controller';
import { users_trans } from './users.entity';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([users_trans])],
  providers: [UsersService],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

The user table looks like this if it helps:

```
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL
USERNAME       TEXT    NOT NULL
PASSWORD       TEXT    NOT NULL
```

Comment: Create a unique index on username column by `@Column({unique: true})`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, because I created the database myself and just linked NestJS to it.

Comment: Then use Typeorm.findOne to fetch user by username too see if it exists or not before creating it

Comment: You create the database yourself, so create the constraint yourself:  *alter table users_trans add constraint username_uk  unique (username);*

Comment: Okay, so the best way for me really was to let NestJS create my tables for me, thanks for the approach and the nice answers!